# Different precision for different pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a few pandas columns. For some columns I'd like precision to 3 decimal places, for others 2.

I've found if i do a formula like: 
`df[col]=df[col].apply(lambda x:"%.2f" % round(x,2))`
I get the correct precision. But, at that point the sorting goes wrong. For example, the numbers {1,2,11} would sort {1.00,11.00,2.00}.

I can set a particular column to be a float by
 `df[col]=df[col].astype("float")` 
 But then the I lose the decimal precision (1.00 becomes 1.0).
How can I maintain both the decimal precision to be sometimes 2 and sometimes 3 decimal places, while also maintaining a numeric sort order?

Answer (score 1):

Don't convert to strings, round as floats:

```
df[col] = df[col].round(2)
```

Example:

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((3, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))

df['A'] = df['A'].round(1)
df['B'] = df['B'].round(3)
df['C'] = df['C'].round(5)
```

Output:

```
     A      B        C
0  0.5  0.715  0.60276
1  0.5  0.424  0.64589
2  0.4  0.892  0.96366
```

Using a dictionary:

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((3, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))

d = {'A': 1, 'B': 3, 'C': 5}

df[:] = df.apply(lambda s: s.round(d.get(s.name, 10))) # 10 as default
```

Comment: An integer like 1 still is displayed as 1.0, rather than 1.00. I want the trailing zeros where they exist.

Comment: @ryan you have to chose between having floats and being able to perform numerical operations, or strings for the display. If the only issue is sorting, use [`natsort`](https://natsort.readthedocs.io).

Answer (score 0):

You can set display formatting as below -

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.2f}'.format 
OR
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.3f}'.format
```

After that you will get your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the precision when the DataFrame is displayed, you can use panda's `Styler.format`. To make a specific column have a different precision you can format it using a dictionary:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(size=(5, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df.head().style.format({'D':'{:0.3f}'},precision=2)

       A       B       C        D
0   0.24    1.00    0.69    0.630
1   0.99    0.22    0.09    0.342
2   0.33    0.24    0.86    0.037
3   0.65    0.13    0.54    0.184
4   0.50    0.70    0.44    0.185
```